# Touch Labels That Keep Animating

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having an issue trying to touch a label that keeps animating because during the animation it becomes an image (set the animation on repeat). Is there a way to touch it during animation (I cant't use UITapGestureRecognizer) ?

```
func animatePro() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
        //1.5 times it's normal size
        self.proLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }){ (finished) in
            self.proLabel
                .transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}

func animateRev() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: [.repeat], animations: {
        //1.5 times it's normal size
        self.revLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    }){ (finished) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, animations: {
            self.revLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: why can't use `UITapGestureRecognizer` ?

Comment: It's because in that animation state it's an image and UITapGesture can't recognize it.

Comment: no it isn't try it and enable user interaction also for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `allowUserInteraction`

```
options: [.allowUserInteraction,.autoreverse, .repeat]
```